# mySQL: column data to be copied into another column

Tags: mysql, select, copy, insert-into

Apologies for this trivial question but I have tried some of the similar answers supplied here to no avail.

I am creating a single database (merging two sets on Irish census data from 1901 and 1911).

I have a column Age (containing peoples ages) and also a column 1901Age (currently empty). I would like to automatically copy the data in the Age column into 1901Age column.

I am learning SQL on the fly, so am a novice to this but INSERT SELECT and various similar permutations did not work for me.

If I could also do the above with a where column tagged on – the one below filters the results to which I need to apply my above query (if that makes sense!)

```
UPDATE `Census`.`Merged`
SET `Age` = `1901Age`
WHERE (
(
`Age` >= '0'
)
AND (
`1901Age` = '0'
AND `BothCensusStatus` = '1901Only'
```

Comment: I think you're saying your select is ok? If your goal is to copy the age column into the 1901age colummn, then SET `Age` = `1901Age` is wrong? Should be SET `1901Age` = `Age`

Comment: Thank you for that speedy reply. I tried as you suggest but while it does not give an error message it gives 0 results, in other words the data is not copied over from Age to 1901Age.

Answer (score 0):

Probably only minor typos: missing `)` and you write the affectation in reverse order:

```
UPDATE `Census`.`Merged`
SET `1901Age` = `Age`               -- Copy from `Age` to `1901Age`
WHERE `Age` >= 0                    -- Compare on integers
AND `1901Age` = 0                   -- Here again 
                                    -- (BTW, would probably have been better to  
                                    --  use NULL to denote "non-existent" data)
AND `BothCensusStatus` = '1901Only'
```